# Virtual Machine Implementation similar to the JVM

Tags: virtual-machine, cpu, language, c

I'd just like some information about how best to implement a virtual machine. I'd just like to know a couple of things:

1. Is a VM more like a Virtual Computer or a Virtual Processor?
2. What are some best practices when creating a VM?
3. How would you implement things like registers? ( I obviously don't expect anyone to implement a VM for me, but I'd just like even a really really simple example or explanation )
4. Should I use Python or C to implement a VM? ( Which would be better for someone learning? )
5. Should I make lots of instructions or should my VM only have a couple?

Thanks for your help, I realise it might seem like I haven't done any research, but I actually have, I just can't seem to find any good information.

Thanks in advance,
Francis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that it is possible you have the terminology mixed up.

The JVM is not a virtual computer or a virtual processor.

What it is is an interactive compiler. It takes generic (non-processor specific) code (byte code) and compiles it to machine code on the fly. The JVM way of doing this is referred to as a "just in time" compiler.

1. See above
2. Be FAST! You need speed to write something like a JVM
3. Now you are way outside the scope of SuperUser. You need to ask this in another forum
4. Neither. They are nowhere near fast enough.
5. Depends what you want to achieve. Again, this is the wrong forum for answers to questions like that.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. I recommend trying again on the [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) forum which is more suited to the more technical aspects of your question.